# Power analysis: Use a prio test to determine number of particants with G*Power

Tags: t-test, statistical-power, gpower

I would like to conduct a priori power analysis to determine the number of required participants for my experiment. I want to have two experiment groups (with immersive and desktop virtual reality) and compare their errors, time to completion etc. Thus, I chose "t-test with difference between means". A power of 0.8 and a small effect size of 0.2 would be sufficient for me. However, I am very surprised by the very large sample size (see screenshot). I read about similar studies and a sample of around 40 participants per group were more than sufficient in these. Might I have done a mistake in using the program?

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks!

[image: Entered input in G*Power]

Comment: The pwr package in R agrees with this: pwr::pwr.t.test(d = 0.2, sig.level = 0.2, power = 0.8, type = "two.sample", alt = "greater") Is alpha = 0.2 what you want?

Comment: Try with a larger effect size